# нужно запускать андроид приложение из моего Unity приложения

Tags: c#, android, unity3d

я использую Unity 2020, и мне нужно запускать андроид приложения нажав на кнопку в моем Unity приложении. вот код, который я увидел на ондном форуме:

```
void StartPackage(string package)
{
AndroidJavaClass activityClass;
AndroidJavaObject activity, packageManager;
AndroidJavaObject launch;


    activityClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    activity = activityClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
    packageManager = activity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getPackageManager");
    launch = packageManager.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getLaunchIntentForPackage", package);
    activity.Call("startActivity", launch);
}
```

вот ссылка на сам вопрос: https://answers.unity.com/questions/780406/androidunity-launching-activity-from-unity-activit.html
пользователь с ником RexetStudio написал что используя только этот код(без java кода) можно запускать другое приложение из моего Unity приложения...
Если это так, то можно небольшое уточнение от более опытных людей: если мне например нужно запускать Viber при нажатии на кнопку, то мне нужно в этой строке

```
         activity = activityClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
```

изменить "currentActivity" на "Viber"? или как?) подскажите пожалуйста...

Comment: `currentActivity` - это метод получения активности вашего приложения, которая сейчас на переднем плане. Активность вайбера в этом коде указывать не нужно -  `getLaunchIntentForPackage` возвращает полноценный интент для запуска главной активности приложения. А вот в переменной `package` должен быть указан `application id` вайбера. Этот код просто запустит стартовую активность как-будто приложение запустили с ярлыка.

Comment: огромное спасибо Вам за комментарий! а если нужно запускать например камеру, то там уже какая-то другая схема? еще раз спасибо!